# Custom sidebar isn't showing up on sub-category posts

Tags: categories, sidebar

I have a magazine style website that has custom sidebars. If someone posts something under the category of Culture, I have culture sidebar that shows up. Under entertainment, the entertainment sidebar shows, etc. The problem I'm having is that the correct sidebar doesn't show if someone writes an article using a sub-category and not picking the parent category. So if someone just picks a subcategory of culture, the culture category won't show up. I've included my code from my sidebar.php page. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

```
 <aside id="secondary" class="widget-area">
<?php
 
 if ( in_category('culture') ) {
  
 dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-1' );
  
 }elseif ( in_category('entertainment') ) {
  
 dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-2' );

 }elseif ( in_category( 'arts'  ) ) {
 dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-3' );

}elseif ( in_category( 'eat'  ) ) {
    dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-4' );

}elseif ( in_category( 'opinion'  ) ) {
    dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-5' );

}elseif ( in_category( 'music'  ) ) {
    dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-6' );
 
 }else{
  
 dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-1' );
  
 }
  
 ?>
```

Comment: Your code is good, but it's just that `in_category()` only returns true if the post is directly attached to the specified category/categories. So if you had 2 categories - one parent named `Foo` and the other a child named `Bar`, and only the `Bar` category that was selected for the post, then `in_category( 'Bar' )` would return true, but not `in_category( 'Foo' )`.

Comment: Therefore, for `in_category()` to return true, you would need to select both the `Foo` and `Bar` categories (when you create/edit your post), or pass them both to `in_category()`, e.g. `in_category( array( 'Foo', 'Bar' ) )`.